# Numpy vector of function applyed to vector of arguments

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

I run "cprofiler" on my code and I observed a bottle-neck in the following code

```
self.h = np.array([func1, func2, func3])
X = np.array([[100,1023,333],[86,8023,73]])
np.sign(self.w[:max_t] @ [f.predict(X) for f in self.h[:max_t]])
```

(*self.w[:max_t] is just an numpy array of floats)

I know the bottle neck is from the list comprehension,
note the above code which runs functions from the numpy array "self.h" and creates a new array.

Is there a "numpy" way to do that? I've tried `numpy.vectorize` but I could not find a way to make it work.

Comment: Could you please provide us a reproducible example? maybe a toy function and necessary parts of the class. Thank you.

Comment: Make `self.h` a list.  The iteration will be a bit faster.  `f.predict(x)` for each `f` is what's taking time, not the iteration mechanism itself.

Comment: Why did you try `vectorize`?  Did you read any of its docs?

Comment: @hpaulj why not? do you have any other suggestions to improve it? and how would you apply a vector of functions to vector of arguments?